# How do i update a row where the column varies?

Tags: python, django

This function as you can see updates a users field, where the field depends on the GET variable.

```
def update_p(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        field = request.GET.get("field", "")
        value = request.GET.get("value", "")

        result = Users.objects.raw("SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", [field, request.session['user_id']])[0]
        if result:
            result = getattr(result, field)
            result = value
            result.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/blog/loggedin/profile/")
```

After

```
if result:
```

is where i am getting confused. I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I do not know why i am getting the error ,but hopefully its self-explanatory to you all. How can i prevent the error, or is there a better way to do this function?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

By doing `result = getattr(result, field)` you've turned `result` into a `'unicode'` value instead of a `User` object.

You probably meant to write:

```
if result:
    setattr(result, field, value)
    result.save()
```

Comment: Was about to answer this.. Have it your way, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think your string concatenation is incorrect

```
"SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", [field, request.session['user_id']]
```

should be

```
"SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", %(field, request.session['user_id'])
```

For example

```
>>> a = "SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", ["username", "ABC"]
>>> a
('SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1', ['username', 'ABC'])
>>> a = "SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1" %("username", "ABC")
>>> a
'SELECT id, username FROM blog_users WHERE id = ABC LIMIT 1'
```

also valid SQL would require the ABC to be in quotes "ABC"